# Where does Homebrew install Postgres executables?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

Which directory does Homebrew install Postgres executables in? I've searched just about everywhere.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the `bin/` directory managed by Homebrew. Pop open a terminal and run:

```
$ echo `brew --prefix`/bin
```

The output will be the directory where Postgres executables are installed.

Comment: yes. and in case anyone is searching for the bin/ dir managed by Homebrew... try /opt/homebrew/bin

Comment: If you don't find it in `/opt/homebrew/bin`, try `/opt/homebrew/opt`

Answer (score 22):

Usually you can find recipes in /usr/local/Cellar .  Did you try searching there?

Answer (score 3):

For version 14 location is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@14
```

Use the complete version to find the executables:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.8/lib/postgresql@14
```